# How to identify strings that don't *contain* any of a list of other strings

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have Column A and Column B with text. 
I want to copy Column A to Column C and remove rows
that equal ***or contain*** a value in Column B.

I have this formula but it doesn't remove containing rows, only matching:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNA(MATCH(A:A,B:B,0)),A:A,""))
```

Any formula/query for this?

[image: screen shot]

(Note that I want `C2` to be blank,
because `A2`, `sevdaa`, ***contains*** `sevda` (`B3`).)

Comment: At quick glance, it's "sevdaa" in column A and "sevda" in column B which is why it shows up in column C still.

Comment: @T0t3sMcG0t3s I know. I dont want "sevdaa" to be copied because it contains "sevda"

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
=IF(AND(A1<>"", PRODUCT(--ISERROR(FIND(B$1:B$3,A1)))>0), A1, "")
```

into `C1` and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
Then drag/fill down.

- `FIND(B$1:B$3,A1)` checks
  whether each word/name in cells `B1` through `B3`
  is found within the word/name in cell `A1`. 
  This will evaluate to an integer offset if there is a match
  and a `#VALUE!` error if there is not.
- `ISERROR(…)` evaluates to TRUE if the inner formula is an error
  (i.e., if there is no match) and FALSE otherwise (i.e., if there is a match).
- `--` converts TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0. 
  So `--ISERROR(FIND(B$1:B$3,A1))` will be all 1s
  if `A1` doesn’t contain `B1`, `B2`, or `B3`,
  but will hold some 0s if there are any strings in `B1:B3` that appear in `A1`.
- And so `PRODUCT(…)` is 1 if all the numbers are ones,
  and 0 if any of them are zeroes.
- So, if `A1` is not blank, but it doesn’t contain any of the `B` strings,
  then display that word/name in Column `C`.